# PSQL Command Line Not Interactive

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a postgres container running with docker-copose which is defined like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

I can either use the terminal inside docker desktop or from the command line like so

`docker exec -t CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres`

This appears to connect just fine to postgres in the container. However, when I try a simple query to see if it's working correctly I get no feedback.

`postgres=# select 1 + 1 as sum;`

No results. I can continue typing and hitting enter but nothing happens.

I'm on MacOs with M2-Pro running Ventura 13.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have interactive connection on a docker container you need to use this:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres
```

The `-i` makes the session interactive.